# Creating alarms for existing SQS queues using script

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sqs, amazon-cloudwatch, alarm

I am trying to create alarms based on existing SQS queue metrics in my AWS account using cloud formation. I have more than 25 SQS queues and don't want to repeat the code where I mention the SQS queues one by one. Is there an effective method (shorter code) to create the alarms using programming?

Here is the YAML code for the CloudFormation template. In this, I have mentioned one of the queues from my existing queues.

```
Parameters:
  SQSAlarm:
    Type: String
    Description: Alarm for existing SQS Queues
    Default: Queue1
  SQSAlarm:
    Type: String
    Description: Alarm for existing SQS Queues
    Default: Queue3

Resources:
  MyAlarm:
    Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm
    Properties:
      AlarmName:
        !Ref SQSAlarm
      MetricName: "QueueName"
      Namespace: AWS/SQS
      Statistic: Average
      Period: 60
      EvaluationPeriods: 1
      Threshold: 60
      ComparisonOperator: GreaterThanThreshold
      MetricName: ApproximateAgeOfOldestMessage
      AlarmActions:
        - arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:589557565942:SQS-Oldest-Message
      Dimensions:
        - Name: QueueName
          Value: !Ref SQSAlarm
```

Comment: Do you have any code to show, demonstrating what you have and try to achieve?

Comment: Hi, Here is the code that I have written in YAML as a cloud formation template. Using this method I have to list all the existing queues one by one and later create alarms for each of them individually. I want a more effective method than this as I am repeating the code blocks in this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There are no loops** in CloudFormation (CFN). The only solutions for you would be as follows:

- create [CFN macro](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-macros.html), to auto generate the queues definitions automatically.
- create a [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) to "manually" create the queues using a lambda function and AWS SDK.
- use [nested stack](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-nested-stacks.html), which still needs to be repeated, but maybe it will be shorter.
- don't use CFN. There are other, much more power IaC tools, such as Terraform, which have loops and reach portfolio of programming techniques which would make it easy to auto-generate those queues.